# MySQL JSON - group by JSON array index

Tags: mysql, json

I'm trying to count number of nested JSON array elements grouped by parent index using MySQL 8 JSON type field. My JSON string looks like

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "b": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]
    },
    {
      "b": [
        1
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to get the count of elements under "b" key for each "a" element. I need an output similar to:

```
{0: 3, 1: 1}
```

Meaning that a[0] has 3 elements under "b", while a[1] has 1.

This query counts total number of "b" elements across all "a"s (yields 4):

`select JSON_LENGTH(json->>'$.a[*].b[*]') from myTable`

Is it possible to somehow group it by **a**'s index?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) and [JSON_OBJECTAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg):

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_OBJECTAGG(
    `rowid` - 1,
    JSON_LENGTH(`count`)
  )
FROM JSON_TABLE(
  '{"a":[{"b":[1,2,3]},{"b":[1]}]}',
  '$.a[*]'
  COLUMNS(
    `rowid` FOR ORDINALITY,
    `count` JSON PATH '$.b'
  )
) `der`;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w1j2G92kUSqvKqCRCy5jKF/1).